# Python 3.x - nunique does not work with groupby

Tags: group-by, unique

I need to calculate the number of unique users from a df. I am using the groupby function -

```
df - 
col1 col2 col3 col4
a    p    x    7 
a    p    x    3
b    q    y    5
b    r    y    2
c    s    z    5
c    t    z    9

Unique_df = df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3'],as_index=False)['col4'].nunique()
```

**Expected output**

```
Unique_df -
col1 col2 col3 col4
a    p    x    2 
b    q    y    1
b    r    y    1
c    s    z    1
c    t    z    1
```

Unfortunately i get the following error - 
AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'nunique'

How can i get the expected output?

EDIT - 
I tried -

```
df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3'],as_index=False)['col4'].apply(lambda x: len(x.unique()))
```

But unfortunately it gives me a Series -

```
col1 col2 col3 
a    p    x    7 
a    p    x    3
b    q    y    5
b    r    y    2
c    s    z    5
c    t    z    9
```

I do not want this. I want a dataframe as I mentioned in the 'Expected Output'

I tried to convert this series to dataframe using - 
pd.DataFrame(df)

But this gives -

```
               col4
col1 col2 col3 
a    p    x    7 
a    p    x    3
b    q    y    5
b    r    y    2
c    s    z    5
c    t    z    9
```

Again, this is different from 'Expected Output'

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for pandas, the return value for nunique function is supposed to be only a series.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html

I tested your code. The only time I got the output to be a data frame was when I did as below. Where I did mention the as_index parameter and removed the length calculation for the nunique values.

```
>>> var1 = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']).apply(lambda x:x.nunique())
>>> type(var1)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

>>> var2 = var1 = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']).apply(lambda x:len(x.nunique()))
>>> type(var2)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

It seems like when I try to use as_index=False and the Len() function, the value becomes a series instead of a dataframe. Unsure if this solves the problem. But I hope it helps you try different options. I suggest putting the different combinations into variables and testing their type and behaviour as you change them.

```
>>> var1 = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']).apply(lambda x:x.nunique())
>>> var1
                     col1  col2  col3  col4
col1 col2 col3 col4                        
a    p    x    2        1     1     1     1
b    q    y    1        1     1     1     1
     r    y    1        1     1     1     1
c    s    z    1        1     1     1     1
     t    z    1        1     1     1     1

>>> type(var1)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same problem a few days ago. I used group.nunique() which worked on my computer but did not worked on another.

I resolved this by updating anaconda (conda update --all). I suspect (but don't take my word on that) that it is caused by an outdated numpy library (conda update numpy)...

I hope it helps !